# Show multiple figures by calling function repeatedly

Tags: python, function, matplotlib

I have a function that I call to create a fancy plot, using multiple subplots configured with gridspec. It works great for a single call, but I would like to call it repeatedly to create N figures (instead of doing it one-by-one). What I observe in attempting to call it multiple times, is the single plot I get is the last one I requested.

I attempted to put the `plt.show()` only within the calling code, but that did not work. In fact, I did not call `plt.show()` at all, but yet I still got my plot to show.

Note that I'm using Spyder and have the plots pop-out within their own window (not in-line). Below are the salient parts of my function.

```
def FancyPlot(Signal, Time, HSdt, Axis):
    ax = [Axis +101, Axis +102, Axis +103, Axis +104]
    gs = gridspec.GridSpec(2, 3,width_ratios=[1, 2, 0.5], height_ratios=[4, 1.5])
    
    ax[1] = plt.subplot(gs[1])                   # ax102
    ax[0]  = plt.subplot(gs[0], sharey=ax[1])  # ax101
    ax[2]  = plt.subplot(gs[2])                   # ax103
    ax[3]  = plt.subplot(gs[4], sharex=ax[1])  # ax104
    
    (f, S)= scipy.signal.welch(Signal, 1/HSdt, nperseg=4*1024) #nperseg=1024
    ax[0].loglog(S, f)
    ax[3].plot(Time, Signal)
    ax[2].plot(Time, Signal)

    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

In Spyder, go to Tools>Preferences>IPython console>Graphics backend

Choose "Inline"

Rather than popping out the plots will appear in the plots pane. But you will see each of them, not just the last.

Or you might consider using a Jupyter notebook which would have the same effect.